# Apple ITMS Transporter: How to Upload screenshot for ios-iPad Pro?

Tags: ipad, itmstransporter

Using Apple's **ItmsTransporter Java utility**, I want to upload screenshots for the new iPad Pro.

Even after completely re-installing the software and deleting the .itmstransporter/ directory, plus using "itms lookup", I still get the **following error message**:

> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-3000: "Line 25 column 80: value of attribute "display_target" is invalid; must be equal to "Mac", "iOS-3.5-in", "iOS-4-in", "iOS-4.7-in", "iOS-5.5-in", "iOS-Apple-Watch" or "iOS-iPad" at XPath /package/software/software_metadata/versions/version/locales/locale/software_screenshots/software_screenshot"

Note that any option regarding **"iPad Pro" or similar is missing** from this list.

What do I have to do in order to **make this upload possible?**

Comment: Trying to do the same thing. Apple is TERRIBLE with this iTMSTransporter service. They even have a bug in countring bytes vs countring unicode characters. I reported it to them, nothing happened. And now they have ipad pro missing it seems? Argh!

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Hi Eugenio,

no, the last time we tried (a few weeks ago I think), the option was still missing. It seems they simply haven't ever implemented it.

Comment: @BetLamed see the answer by @ kmg below.  It solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I believe if the package version is declared as "software5.4",  it should work.

```
<package xmlns="http://apple.com/itunes/importer" version="software5.4">
```

From https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27043, quoted below.

> mobile.certification
>   Jul 26, 2016 9:21 AM
>   (in response to Scotty)
>   Hello,
>
> While i hope you've managed to fix your issues already, here's what solved me my problem.
>
> Apparently in order to persuade the transporter app / Apple servers to recognise the iPAD Pro Display Target, you'll need to declare the package version in the
>
> My metadata.xml files are using something like bellow:
>
> And i can inject iPAD Pro
>
> Let me know if it helped
>
> Best
>   n.

Comment: This is the best thing that could have happened to me today!  This issue had affect me for so long, and I thought that Apple was just being lazy about updating ITMS Transporter.  Thank you so much for posting this!!!

Comment: @EugenioDeHoyos no problem! Glad to help